# Can't telnet to mysql on 3306 from other vps

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, telnet

My vps system verion is Ubuntu 16.04.1 x64.
Mysql version is 5.5.48

I have tried various methods to support 3306.

I have updated "etc/my.cnf" file to commented "'skip-networking" and have the "bind-address" to be 0.0.0.0;

and I use "netstat -an | grep 3306" to check the port status, I got the result:

```
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:3306 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:35498 127.0.0.1:3306 TIME_WAIT
```

I had shut down my firewall, when I type "ufw status", I got:

```
Status: Inactive
```

But after all the step and reboot my vps, I type "telnet 128.XXX.XXX.27 3306" on other vps, I got:

```
telnet: connect to address 128.XXX.XXX.27: Operation timed out
```

**But the strange thing is when I type "telnet localhost 3306" on the local vps, it works fine.**

So What could be possible problems? I could provide more details you want.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there a firewall?

Comment: firewall is Inactive.

Comment: On both the machines, and the network?

Comment: My own machine telnet 3306 also need to close the firewall? My own machine is Macbook, should not have firewall. and what is the network's firewall? How to close it?

Comment: I solved it. It was a problem with the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

It was a problem with the firewall.

Although I turned off the firewall, but the rule of the iptables are still affect all network requests, and use "iptables -L", I found that:

DROP     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:mysql

The beginning is "DROP", and the end is "mysql".

After I removed this line, everything is fine.